# Is the meaning of ありあまる negative or positive?

Tags: expressions

According to the dictionary on my MacBook Pro, ありあまる means "be [have*] more than enough". I was thinking about the song by [ゲスの極み乙女:ロマンスがありあまる](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsFJgNQfwcg) when I first heard the word/expression.

The question boils down to if I can use ありあまる as a positive expression

`ロマンスがありあまる I have lots of romance, and that is a good thing`

or a negative expression

`ロマンスがありあまる I am fed of with romance, and that is a bad thing`

Or maybe it is context dependent?
The dictionary also provides me with two examples

▸ 精力が有り余っている
have too much [an excess of] energy.

▸ 彼には有り余るほどの金がある
He has more money than he can spend.

But I still do not know if they are meant as negative or positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the English expressions, "too many," "too much," and "more than he can spend", are negative, grammatically.
I believe that they are affirmative expressions.

However, I agree that they would mean something that has a ***bad*** connotation.In other words, a ***negative*** connotation.
And I believe that you're asking about this point. In that case, I'd say, "It depends on the context."

A "精力がありあまっている" guy may have a lot of girlfriends and tend to have immoral love affairs. So I think it would mean something bad, when I think of the moral.

> 彼は精力がありあまっていて生き生きしている。実にうらやましい。

In this sentence, however, the writer apparently envies him. So they probably think that it's a good thing for him or for them.

> 彼には有り余るほどの金がある。

In this case, I envy him, and I personally don't think it's bad thing to be rich for him.

In short, it depends on the context and you cannot decide which grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the translation, in the context of the song, and put into natural-sounding English, is along the lines of:

"There must be love for me somewhere..."

When you google "ari-amaru", there's one link that shows translations from mundane documents...

[https://www.linguee.com/japanese-english/translation/ありあまる.html]

...and it's clear from the examples that although in English we end up using the single word "have", the meaning in Japanese is more emphatic.  "You must have third-party insurance coverage if you buy a car in Australia..."; "Diabetes is almost always a co-morbidity when a person has cardiovascular disease..."; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the above:   looks like I got it backwards.

"Ari-amaru" is "I have lots of...";  see this translation of the song:

[ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OelvXQZGuC0 ]

Comment: Hello. Maybe you can register an account and merge these two posts to your account, so you can properly edit/update your posts. You get to the contact form at the bottom of the page ("Contact").